# Notation question - How to select a digit or range from number?

Tags: number-theory

Let's say that my number A = 123456789
I want (mathematically speaking) to express the selection of the 5th digit starting from right. In this case, the number 5.

Which math notation should I use to describe those ideas?

In programming languages this is super easy (under language rules + mod 2 arithmetic) picking the correct bit.

Best..

Comment: The  coefficient of $10^4$ in the decimal expansion, or for the nth digit from the right, the coefficient of $10^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this algebraically, note that the $k$th digit of any number $n$ in base $b$ is

$$\bigg{\lfloor} \dfrac{n}{b^k} \bigg{\rfloor} \pmod{b}$$

where we divide by $b^k$ and floor to cut off all the digits below the $k$th and to shift the $k$th digit into the ones place, and we mod by $b$ to cut off all digits above the $k$th. This might not be convenient, depending on why you want this, but it certainly works.

Comment: Hi Will, got it. I was think if I could to it in a less verbose manner. My intention was to find a less verbose formalism to represente things like in RTL Verilog: Take the original value in Register[7:0]. Now I want Register[5:3] or Register[3:5]

Comment: My interest is to avoid the sea of symbol definitions to work on equations. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm a relatively new mathematician (still in college) so I don't have the background to know if such a notation already exists. Though depending on why you need this couldn't you define you own notation? For example, you could say "Let $n:k$ be defined as the $k$th digit of the number $n$" or you could define a function $N_b(k,n) : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}_b$ defined to be the $k$th digit of $n$ in base $b$. Sometimes new notation might be better than trying to dig out old notation.

Comment: Yes, agree. Asking for the sake to avoid reinvent the wheel. Defining a new notation also requires to express on how to manipulate and use it algebraically

Comment: lol about your first wish of a "less verbose manner"

Comment: I can't imagine the notation I used would be too cumbersome to explain algebraically just because of the nature of what you're dealing with, then again I suppose it depends on what you want to do with the notation.

Comment: @JeanMarie might be controversial but certainly ironic to look for a less verbose notation when you are planning to pick digits. :-)